# passing null to overriden method

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
class SuperClass {

    int method(Object o){
        return 1;
    }

    int method(String s){
        return 2;
    }
}
public class PassingNull extends SuperClass {

    int method(Object s) {
        return 3;
    }
    public static void main(String... a){
        SuperClass sc = new SuperClass();
        PassingNull sb = new PassingNull();
        SuperClass st = new PassingNull();
        System.out.println(sc.method(null)); //1
        System.out.println(sb.method(null)); //2
        System.out.println(st.method(null)); //3
    }
}
```

I understand that for 1 and 3, it prints '2' because that **most specific parameter type** is called. But not able to understand why 2 prints '2'.

Comment: My guess would be it's the same reason why 1 and 3 print `2`: it's using `method(String)` rather than your overriden `method(Object)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, for the same reason as cases 1 and 2.

`SuperClass` has two methods named `method`, as you know. One of them takes an `Object` and the other takes a `String`, and the latter is more specific -- so passing `null` refers to the second (more specific) method, since `null` is applicable to both.

Now, `PassingNull` *also* has two methods named `method`. Like before, one overload takes `Object` (the one that overrides `SuperClass::method(Object)`), and the other one takes `String` (the one that's inherited straight from `SuperClass`). So it's a similar situation, meaning that the type resolution will work similarly: given that both overloads are applicable, the more specific one -- the one that takes `String` -- is the one that will get invoked.